# How to send Synchronous Requests with $http of Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, sendasynchronousrequest

hey guys I know this issue posted a lot, but nothing doesn't help me that is why I asking this question.Question is I am facing an issue of sending a synchronous request to php. 
here is my Model function which is sending request.

```
State.pushData = function () {
    $http({
    method: 'POST',

    url: 'pushData.php?action=pushdata',
    data: {'status': 'push', 'email' : State.campemail},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(response){
        if(response.error){
          console.log(response.error);
          return;
        }
        State.getCartData();
        State.selectedItems = [],
    });
}
```

this pushData function send a post request to defined url. and fetch a response. the code written is suppose to execute "State.getCartData()" function on success of request sent initially. But this is not working in this way. both request executes at once.
I had tried $http with .post and then methods but same results. like this

```
   State.pushData = function () {
    $http.post('pushData.php?action=pushdata',
    {'status': 'push', 'email' : State.campemail}
    ).then(function(response){
        if(response.error){
          console.log(response.error);
          return;
        }
        State.getCartData();
        State.selectedItems = [],
    });
}
```

I want to send request asynchronously, that once pushQuote request completes after that getCartData() function will execute. please share your experience on this. thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your issue is not in the snippet you posted. There's no way `State.getCartData();` can be triggered before the promise is resolved. You should find out where `State.getCartData();` is triggered. A simple way to do so, is this snippet: `console.info((new Error()).stack);` This will log an Error-stack without actually throwing one, but it will show you the last 10 steps your application took to execute `getCartData`. Hope this helps.

Comment: here is the controller function calling this model function.
    scope.pushIt = function () {
         console.log("pushing Data to server");
         State.pushData();
        }
here is nothing but just a call of pushData().

Comment: Could you put `console.info((new Error()).stack);` as the first thing that `getCartData` executes? And edit the stack-trace into your post.

Comment: nop, it didn't helped me. stack is logged is not even much clearer, it is showing me just URLS of the files which are involved in following :
uf/this.$get
uf/this.$get
Kc[b]</<.compile/</
 b.event.dispatch
b.event.add/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got an answer to my question after some brainstorming. I return $http in my model and call .then() on returned response. it worked as I want to send request once first is completed successfully. Here is my model function

```
State.pushData = function () {
  return $http.post('pushData.php?action=pushdata',
  {'status': 'push', 'email' : State.campemail}
  );
}
```

in above function I just send post request to server and return its response to controller function. which executes right after returning from model. here is my controller function.

```
scope.pushIt = function() {
  var responseObj = State.pushData();
  responseObj.then(
    function() { //successs call back
      /*Business logic*/
      State.getCartData();
      State.selectedItems = []
    },
    function() { //Error call back
      /*Business logic*/
    }
  );
}
```

Beauty of this approach is you can use then method as many as you want. they will all execute one by one in chain.

```
scope.pushIt = function() {
 var responseObj = State.pushData();
  responseObj.then(
  function() { //successs call back
   /*Business logic*/
   },
  function() { //Error call back
   /*Business logic*/
  }
 ).then(
   function() { //successs call back
   /*Business logic*/
   },
   function() { //Error call back
    /*Business logic*/
   }
 );
}
```